# How to reset schema password without any length restriction criteria in Oracle Database?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, alter, change-password

Password reset error in Oracle database, please find below:

```
SQL> alter user test_user identified by pteis34;
alter user test_user identified by pteis34
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-28003: password verification for the specified password failed
ORA-20002: Password length less than 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the below statements to reset password:

```
SQL> select username,profile from dba_users where username='TEST_USER';

USERNAME                       PROFILE
------------------------------ ------------------------------
TEST_USER                       DEFAULT

SQL>

SQL> select profile, limit from dba_profiles where resource_name = 
'PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION' and profile='DEFAULT';

PROFILE                        LIMIT
------------------------------ ----------------------------------------
DEFAULT                        VERIFY_PASSWORD_FUNCTION


SQL> ALTER PROFILE "DEFAULT" LIMIT PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION null;

Profile altered.

SQL> alter user TEST_USER identified by pteis34;

User altered.

SQL> ALTER PROFILE "DEFAULT" LIMIT PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION VERIFY_PASSWORD_FUNCTION;

Profile altered.

SQL> conn TEST_USER/pteis34@DB_STRING
Connected.
SQL> show user
USER is "TEST_USER"
SQL>
```